# How can I use a variable from a another function in the same class?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.3

In my program have I a Button that when I pressed it's get the `rara` entry.
But it doesn't work. Has anyone got an idea of what could be the problem?

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import tkinter.messagebox

class Application(Frame):
    """ GUI aplication hoger of lager"""
    def __init__(self,master):
        """Instaleerd het Frame"""
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        Application.rarara=0;Application.aantal=0;Application.max_pogingen=10;Application.ikdenkaan=random.randrange(1,100)
        self.main()
        master.after(1,self.welkom)

    def welkom(self):
        """Create Widgets voor het spelletje hoger of lager"""
        #Verwelkomingslebels en instructielabels
        msgb=tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("uitleg",
                                         "Welkom bij het spelletje'hoger of lager'.\nIk heb zojuist aan een getal tussen 1 en 100 gedacht.\nJij mag dat getal raden en je hebt 10 pogingen."
                                         )
    def labels(self):
        #ik denk aan label
        Label(self,
              text="Ik denk aan:"
              ).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)


    def invoer(self):
        rara=Entry(self)
        rara.config(width=5)
        rara.grid(row=0, column=1,sticky=W)
        rara.configure(state="normal")

    def naknopindruk(self):
        ikdenkaan=Application.ikdenkaan
        max_pogingen=Application.max_pogingen
        aantal=Application.aantal
        rara=Application.invoer.rara
        rarara=rara.get()
        Application.aantal+=1
        if rarara==ikdenkaan and max_pogingen !=aantal:
            msgb2=tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("winaar","je hebt het juiste getal geraden.\nJe hebt het in "+aantal+" gedaan")

    def knop(self):
        Button(self,text="raad",command=self.naknopindruk).grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=[W,E])

    def main(self):
        self.labels()
        self.invoer()
        self.knop()

root=Tk()
root.title("Hoger of lager")
root.geometry("+533+244")
app=Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to save a reference to `rara`. For example:

```
self.rara = Entry(...)
...
rarara = self.rara.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access 'rara' again you need to save a reference to it. At the end of your function just add the following code:
    self.rara = rara

and when you need to access it again, you can get the property with self.rara
Be careful you've initialized it before you try and access it though, as you could get errors.